# visitors need to click ctrl f5 for changes on website

Tags: html, caching

On my website in my head i have this:

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

But still, visitors on my website need to click ctrl+f5 to see changes on the website. Why is this so??

Comment: change your meta tag to this `<meta HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">` see if it helps

Comment: worked thank you please post as anwser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change you meta tag a little bit instead of the 0 you need a -1

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
```